# Как обработать любое нажатие по клавише Enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующий код:

```
 $("#fio_pokup").keydown(function(e){
    id_box = $(this).attr("id");
    quer = $("#fio_pokup").val();; //присваиваем переменную
if (e.keyCode == '13') { //если нажат Enter
if(quer!='') { //если переменная не пустая
$(this).addClass('true');
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", //тип запроса
    url: "modules/kvitok/update.php", //куда далаем запрос
    dataType:"json", // тип json
    data:{
        value: quer, // данные
        sid: session_id, // сессионная переменная
        id: id_box //имя id атрибута
    }, //отправляем данные
    success:function(data){
        var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data); //парсим ответ
            if (res["msg"]=="Ok"){ // если все ОК
                $.unblockUI(); // отображаем всплывающее окно
                $.growlUI('Успешно!', 'Фамилия покупателя установлена!'); //сообщение в окне
            }
            else{ // если все плохо
                if (confirm(res["msg"])) { //показываем сообщение
                    close(); // закрываем окно
                }
            }
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError); //выводим ошибку
                          }
        });
 }}});
```

оно отлавливает нажатие Enter только в поле с id=fio_pokup. Делать на каждое поле аналогичный код - не по феншую, в связи с чем был введен id_box, который этот id и отправит на сервер, указав, с какого поля отправлены данные. Далее, форма такая:

```
<div id="kvitok">
<input type="text" size="50" maxlength="100" value="" id="fio_pokup"/><br>
<input type="text" size="50" maxlength="100" value="" id="adress_pokup"/>
</div>
```

Вопрос: Как отредактировать этот код, чтобы он:
1) Ловил любое нажатие Enter где div id="kvitok"
2) Вычислил id инпута
3) Вычислил value инпута

Comment: если указать $('html').keydown(function(e){
то он не хочет вычислять id_box = $(this).attr("id");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте селектор на все инпуты: `$("input")`, [пример:](https://fiddle.jshell.net/h2b6bnn7/3/)

```
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == '13') { 
            id_box = $(this).attr("id");
            alert(id_box);
    }
});
```